# Error trying to display Amadeus Test API for Hotel data in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I'm testing Amadeus Test API for Hotel. I have Access Token. The JSON data is available. I used JS fetch to display the data in a web page but I have http error:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol

```
"use_strict";
function searchHotel(){
 let url = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=PEK&checkInDate=2020-12-01&chechOutDate=2020-12-03";
 fetch(url).then(response => {
     return response.json();
 }).then(results => {
     //display data
     //var results JSON.parse(result);
       console.log(results);
       document.getElementById('hotelname').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',results.data[0].hotel.name);
      //document.getElementById("hotelname").innerHTML = results.data[0].hotel.name;
     //hotelname.innerHTML = result.data[0].hotel.name;
 }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
 });
}

searchHotel();
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a warning. But anyway why not declaring the encoding? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Localizations_and_character_encodings

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid. I forgot that

Comment: I must be getting something wrong. The data still does not appear in the webpage

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. When I call this API I get `Missing or invalid format for mandatory Authorization header` which means the auth headers are missing. I assume you have added them? It's not enough here to make any sort of suggestion